# Don't find how to link to user_post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new on rails, I work on a application. My user can create a post, post belong to user. On my index user I want to link_to the user_post for each user, I try a lot of solution, but nothing work...

_list.html.erb :

```
<div id="filterrific_results">

<div>
  <%= page_entries_info users %>
</div>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% if user.coach? %>
    <h1><%= user.fname %> <%= user.lname %></h1>
    <h2><%= user.mother_tongue %></h2>
      <center>
        <p><%= user.postal_code %> <%= user.locality %></p>

        <p><%= link_to "En savoir plus", **user_post_path** %></p>
      </center>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>


<%= will_paginate users %>
```

> Edit : The routes :

```
  resources :users do
    resources :post
  end
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: So the problem is with `user_post_path`? What routes have you defined? (What's in the relevant portion of `config/routes.rb`?) What routes does rails know about? (Run: `rake routes`, and look at the relevant parts.) Most likely, what you need to do is: `user_posts_path(user)` - but without knowing how you've set up the application, I cannot say anything for certain.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `ruby-on-rails-3`, `ruby-on-rails-4` *and* `ruby-on-rails-5`? Which version are you actually using? Pick one.

Comment: I have the error with user_post_path(user) : _No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"post", :user_id=>#}, missing required keys: [:id]_                                          I use Rails 5

Answer (score 0):

Is it a has_one relation between user and post.
You can make a nested route for the post like

```
resource :user do
  resource :post, only: [:create]
end
```

Comment: Yes the users just have one post (I edit the post with the route)

Comment: @BenjaminRichard Can you please upvote. So I am able to post answer further.

Answer (score 0):

You said "posts" belong to "user", I assume that means you're using a `has_many` and `belongs_to`. If that is not the case, please note that plural vs singular matters. Given that, you'll need to pull the specific post from the `ActiveRecordRelation`. See the following:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.fname %> 
  #etc
  <% user.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= link_to post.title, post %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This assumes you have set up in your routes `resources :users, :posts`

Comment: A user have just one post, sorry my bad

Comment: It's working with belong_to instead of belongs_to in the post.rb and with user.post for the link_to. Thanks to all for your help

Comment: @BenjaminRichard *"It's working with belong_to instead of belongs_to"* are you sure about that ? `belong_to` without "s" doesn't exist in rails...

Comment: @sovalina when he posted that comment originally it said `belongs_in` so I think he's a touch confused.